# how to use robot_pose_ekf module to improve odom data and use that to produce better maps

Tags: navigation, odometry, gmapping, robot-pose-ekf, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on building maps of my office ( which is think is around 100 * 100 mts) . I using  [this](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) tutorial for gmapping. This is the procedure i follow to create the map.

1. I run the robot in a loop ( around a huge rectangular cubical). I wrote a simple obstacle avoidance code in python for this. I am not teleoperating it.
2. i save /tf and Laserscan data in a bag file.
3. Once i collect the data, i follow above tutorial to build the map from logged data.

This is the map i got:
[C:\fakepath\1.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/146967725626134.png)

Which you can see is a very bad map.

I can visualize in Rviz that the odometry drifts the more the run the robot around.

So i thought of using [robot_pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf) tutorial to improve odometry. I include the  follow command in my launch file:

To check whether it's working correctly or not, i run the following command:

**rosservice call robot_pose_ekf/get_status**

which gives me the following output:

status: Input:

- Odometry sensor

  - is  active
  - received 5678 messages
  - listens to topic /odom
- IMU sensor

  - is  active
  - received 4567 messages
  - listens to topic /mobile_base/sensors/imu_data
- Visual Odometry sensor

  - is NOT active
  - received 0 messages
  - listens to topic /vo
    Output:
- Robot pose ekf filter

  - is  active
  - sent 4675 messages
  - pulishes on topics /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined and /tf

I changed the odom and imu data topics it is listening to after follwoing some tutorials. It seems like it is getting imu data and odom data.

while i am running the robot around i also save /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined data. And **i plotted both odom and odom_combined data**, which you can see below. As you can see their is no difference in both, blue is odom and red is odom_combined.

[C:\fakepath\figure_1.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14696778954213257.png)

Also in **robot_pose_ekf** tutorials it is said that it will **provide a tf between odom_combined → base_footprint**, but when i run the following command and see the tf tree i cannot find any tf between odom_combined → base_footprint

rosrun tf view frames

[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2016-07-27 20:54:35.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1469678061446060.png)

These are my question:

1. how can i correctly use robot_pose_ekf module to improve odom data?
2. and how can i get the tf between odom_combined → base_footprint?
3. How can i use this information to improve results of gmapping?

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks a ton

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240545/how-to-use-robot_pose_ekf-module-to-improve-odom-data-and-use-that-to-produce-better-maps./) by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to use the robot_pose_ekf package by following these two questions:

[robot_pose_ekf1](http://answers.ros.org/question/37331/gmapping-without-robot_pose_ekf/)

[robot_pose_ekf2](http://answers.ros.org/question/11682/robot_pose_ekf-with-an-external-sensor/?answer=17402#post-id-17402)

---

Originally posted by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) with karma: 63 on 2016-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0